# Mercure issues with changing JWT secret key

Tags: php, vue.js, symfony, mercure

im having problem with my Mercure App,

Im running via docker-compose image of mercure:

```yaml
version: '3.7'
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: localdev

services:
    mercure:
        image: dunglas/mercure
        environment:
            DEBUG: "debug"
            MERCURE_PUBLISHER_JWT_KEY: '!ChangeMe!'
            MERCURE_SUBSCRIBER_JWT_KEY: '!ChangeMe!'
            # In the cors_origin, add your domain(s). Or just use *
            MERCURE_EXTRA_DIRECTIVES: |-
                cors_origins https://localhost
        ports:
                - 1337:80
                - 1338:443
```

and in section with `MERCURE_PUBLISHER_JWY_KEY` and subscriber key im having it set by default to `!ChangeMe!` and it is working as it should.

```js
const url = new URL(
        "https://localhost/.well-known/mercure"
        );
        url.searchParams.append("topic", "chat");
        const eventSource = new EventSource(url, {
            headers: {
                mercureAuthorization: 'Bearer (secret token)',
            },
        });
        eventSource.onmessage = (event) => {
            this.$notify({
                type: "success",
                text: "push",
            });
            console.log(event);
        };
    },
```

And my subscriber in Vue is working when sign part of JWT is `!ChangeMe!` eg:
[image]

But I want to make it secure, so i want to change it to somthing longer and harder to guess. But when im changing it to some sort of hash, my subscriber is not working and im getting 401 Unauthorized errors. But When im pushing data via postman, im getting response and uuid

Postman response with new jwt_key:

[image]

Vue response with new jwt_key:

[image]

Comment: did you restart the Mercure(caddy) server?

Comment: yes, with every change in docker-compose im rebooting mercure server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i solved my problem. Reason was that in `EventSource` was not passing auth header, i've added [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eventsource) polyfill and now its working!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).